# make all <b-collapse> non visible in child.vue when button is clicked in parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have following situation: I have a `parent.vue` and a `child.vue`. In my `parent.vue` I have a `v-for` where I can create multiple `Buttons`. Each of these is triggering a `b-collapse` in my `child.vue` and each of this has multiple `b-collapse` as well. (see Code)

Now I need to do following: I want to close all of my `b-collapse` inside my `child.vue` when my `b-collapse` in my `parent.vue` will be closed. But I could not figure out how to do that.. (they should be closed as well when I reopen my `parent.vue`-collapse)

I have reduced my code to the minimum. But just for additional info I will do `this.inputs.push[{id: this.id +=1}]` each time adding a new Item or Element. So each of them has an `unique id`.

Hopefully someone can help me out!

**CODE**

*parent.vue*

```html
<div v-for="item in inputs" :key="item.id">
  <b-button v-b-toggle="'NewItem'+item.id"></b-button>
</div>

<Child/>

<b-button @click="addNewItem()"></b-button>
```

*child.vue*

```html
<b-collapse visible :id="'NewItem' + item.id">  //Here i need a solution
  <div v-for="element in inputs" :key="element.id">
    <b-button v-b-toggle="'Element' + element.id"></b-button>
    <b-collapse :id="'Element' + element.id>
      <div>Here is Element {{element.id}}</div>
    </b-collapse>
  </div>

  <b-button @click="addElement()"></b-button>
</b-collapse>
```

**EDIT** - Full Code:

*Parent.vue*

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in inputs" :key="item.id">
    <b-button v-b-toggle="'NewItem'+item.id" @click="closeAll()">Item {{index + 1}}</b-button>
  </div>

  <Child :idParent="item.id" :closeAllProducts="closeAllProducts" />

  <b-button @click="addNewItem()">Add new Item</b-button>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import Child from "./components/child.vue"

export default {

  components: {
    Child,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      closeAllProducts: true,
      id: 1,
      inputs: [{
        id: 1,
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addNewItem() {
      this.inputs.push({id: this.id += 1})
    },

    closeAll() {
      this.closeAllProducts = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*Child.vue*

```
<template>
  <b-collapse :visible="closeAllProducts" :id="'NewItem'+item.id">  
    <div v-for="(element, index) in inputs" :key="element.id">
      <b-button v-b-toggle="'Element' + element.id"></b-button>
      <b-collapse :id="'Element' + element.id">
        <div>Here is Element {{index + 1}}</div>
      </b-collapse>
    </div>

    <b-button @click="addElement()">Add new Element</b-button>
  </b-collapse>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["idParent", "closeAllProducts"],

  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      inputs: [{
        id: 1,
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addElement() {
      this.inputs.push({id: this.id += 1})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**NEW EDIT**: Added `closeAllProducts` - If I'm clicking my `button` in my `parent.vue` it should trigger the function to change the `boolean` to `**false**`. But when I use it like this all elements in every item will be `non visible`.. I need to pass a `parameter` with it but I could not figure out how..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to create a child prop that collapses its `b-collapse` elements, and have the parent control that prop:

1. Create a Boolean prop named `collapsed` in the child:

   ```js
   // child.vue
   export default {
     props: {
       collapsed: Boolean
     }
   }
   ```
2. In `addElement()`, insert a `visible` prop to match the `b-collapse`'s `visible` prop. We'll bind each item's `visible` to the corresponding `b-collapse` prop. Note we use `b-collapse`'s `v-model` to bind its `visible` prop, which keeps the item's `visible` prop in sync with the actual visibility state.

   ```html
   <!-- child.vue -->
   <script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         inputs: [
           {
             id: 1,
             visible: false,
           },  
         ],
       }
     },
     methods: {
       addElement() {
         this.inputs.push({ id: ++this.id, visible: false })
       }                                      
     }
   }
   </script>

   <template>
     ⋮                              
     <b-collapse v-model="element.visible" ⋯>
        <div>Here is Element {{ index + 1 }}</div>
     </b-collapse>
   </template>
   ```
3. Add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the `collapsed` prop in the child. This watcher will set each element's `visible` prop to `false` only when `collapsed` is `true`:

   ```js
   // child.vue
   export default {
     watcher: {
       collapsed(collapsed) {
         if (collapsed) {
           this.inputs.forEach(input => input.visible = false)
         }
       },
     }
   }
   ```
4. To ensure each element's ID is globally unique in the context of the parents, incorporate the parent ID into the child IDs:

   ```html
   <!-- child.vue -->
   <div v-for="(element, index) in inputs" :key="element.id">
     <b-button v-b-toggle="'Element' + idParent + '.' + element.id" ⋯>
       ⋯                                   
     </b-button>
     <b-collapse :id="'Element' + idParent + '.' + element.id" ⋯>
       ⋯                             
     </b-collapse>
   </div>
   ```
5. In the parent's `addNewItem()`, add a `collapsed` property. We'll bind each child's `collapsed` prop to this new property, and toggle it upon a button-click:

   ```html
   <!-- parent.vue -->
   <script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         inputs: [
           {
             id: 1,
             collapsed: false,
           },  
         ],
       }
     },
     methods: {
       addNewItem() {
         this.inputs.push({ id: ++this.id, collapsed: false })
       }                                      
     }
   }
   </script>

   <template>
     ⋮
     <div v-for="(item, index) in inputs" :key="item.id">
       <b-button @click="item.collapsed = !item.collapsed">
         ⋯                       
       </b-button>
       <Child :idParent="item.id" :collapsed="item.collapsed" />
     </div>                                          
   </template>
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-collapse-children-from-parent?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fparent.vue)